# Hide S3 download source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm using invisioncommunity forum software with the downloads application.
I serve my visitors downloads trough Amazon S3.

When a file is downloaded, the download source links to my S3 bucket (https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket.net/file), I don't want that.
I want it to look like: https://my.bucket.net/file

Can I use a signed URL or just simply hide the download source? Or what would be the best option?

Also, when I navigate to my bucket URL in my browser (not signed in to S3) I see a XML list with all the files listed in my bucket. Can I hide this?

I've found plenty of content on Google (create CNAME, etc) but nothing seems to really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of this you can use a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) that will actually allow you to use a [custom name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) via your DNS configuration.

This would still return `x-amz` headers so if you wanted to remove those you would need to add a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) to your CloudFront distribution. Here are some [example functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) if you're interested in this approach.

In addition your customers will benefit from less latency if they are located geographically further away from your S3 buckets AWS region.

Regarding the option (the file list), this is coming from the `ListObjects` permission, ensure the only public permission is `GetObject`.

The advised bucket policy for this would be the below one.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
For the second part, do I need to add a key in the Resource part of the policy after my bucket name?

Comment: You would simply replace `awsexamplebucket1` with your bucket name